# Serialization when adding to RedisAggregationRepository

Tags: java, spring-boot, serialization, redis, apache-camel

We are using Apache Camel on one project and we would like to use RedisAggregationRepository when we aggregate some exchanges, but I am having trouble with serialising the body which is the record that contains enum inside.
So my record looks like this (simplified):

```java
@Builder
@Jacksonized
public record NotificationData(
...
        @NotNull
        Type type,
...
)  {

    public enum Type {
        INTERNAL, EXTERNAL
    }
}
```

And I have a route where I use `RedisAggregationRepository` and the NotificationData is a body of the exchange. When adding to Redis is performed the following exception is happening:

```
Exception caught: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: java.io.IOException: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: can't get field offset on a record class: private final NotificationData$Type NotificationData.type
    at org.redisson.command.CommandAsyncService.encodeMapValue(CommandAsyncService.java:732)
    at org.redisson.RedissonObject.encodeMapValue(RedissonObject.java:310)
    at org.redisson.RedissonMap.putOperationAsync(RedissonMap.java:1372)
    at org.redisson.RedissonMap.putAsync(RedissonMap.java:1358)
    at org.redisson.RedissonMap.put(RedissonMap.java:664)
    at org.apache.camel.component.redis.processor.aggregate.RedisAggregationRepository.add(RedisAggregationRepository.java:134)
...


Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: can't get field offset on a record class: private final NotificationData$Type NotificationData.type
    at jdk.unsupported/sun.misc.Unsafe.objectFieldOffset(Unsafe.java:648)
    at org.jboss.marshalling.reflect.SerializableField.<init>(SerializableField.java:58)
    at org.jboss.marshalling.reflect.SerializableClass.getSerializableFields(SerializableClass.java:121)
    at org.jboss.marshalling.reflect.SerializableClass.<init>(SerializableClass.java:88)
    at org.jboss.marshalling.reflect.SerializableClassRegistry$1.computeValue(SerializableClassRegistry.java:62)
    at org.jboss.marshalling.reflect.SerializableClassRegistry$1.computeValue(SerializableClassRegistry.java:59)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassValue.getFromHashMap(ClassValue.java:228)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassValue.getFromBackup(ClassValue.java:210)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassValue.get(ClassValue.java:116)
    at org.jboss.marshalling.reflect.SerializableClassRegistry.lookup(SerializableClassRegistry.java:83)
    at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverMarshaller.doWriteObject(RiverMarshaller.java:180)
    at org.jboss.marshalling.river.BlockMarshaller.doWriteObject(BlockMarshaller.java:65)
    at org.jboss.marshalling.river.BlockMarshaller.writeObject(BlockMarshaller.java:56)
    at org.jboss.marshalling.MarshallerObjectOutputStream.writeObjectOverride(MarshallerObjectOutputStream.java:50)
    at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverObjectOutputStream.writeObjectOverride(RiverObjectOutputStream.java:179)
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:346)
    at java.base/java.util.CollSer.writeObject(ImmutableCollections.java:1465)
    at org.jboss.marshalling.reflect.JDKSpecific$SerMethods.callWriteObject(JDKSpecific.java:89)
    at org.jboss.marshalling.reflect.SerializableClass.callWriteObject(SerializableClass.java:193)
    at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverMarshaller.doWriteSerializableObject(RiverMarshaller.java:1089)
    at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverMarshaller.doWriteObject(RiverMarshaller.java:268)
    at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverMarshaller.doWriteFields(RiverMarshaller.java:1143)
    at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverMarshaller.doWriteSerializableObject(RiverMarshaller.java:1101)
    at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverMarshaller.doWriteObject(RiverMarshaller.java:268)
    at org.jboss.marshalling.AbstractObjectOutput.writeObject(AbstractObjectOutput.java:58)
    at org.jboss.marshalling.AbstractMarshaller.writeObject(AbstractMarshaller.java:111)
    at org.redisson.codec.MarshallingCodec.lambda$new$1(MarshallingCodec.java:161)
    ... 170 more
Caused by: an exception which occurred:
    in field org.apache.camel.support.DefaultExchangeHolder.inBody
    in object org.apache.camel.support.DefaultExchangeHolder@901212
    in object org.apache.camel.support.DefaultExchangeHolder@901212
```

Am I doing something wrong or this is not supported?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I thought this issue is related jboss-marshalling serializer issue. On the below issue, jboss-marshalling doesn't support java records. So, they suggest to use another serializer like Kryo.

- https://github.com/redisson/redisson/issues/4273

And you can choose another serializer by referring below redisson official document.

- https://github.com/redisson/redisson/wiki/4.-data-serialization

Thanks